# Assign shortcut keys to VBA macros when manually compiling PERSONAL.xlsb using Excel Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-interop

This is a niche problem so I will try to define everything to the best of my ability. I am using Excel 2007.

Our company uses excel to produce our forms. We have many workers who use these forms. We do not want our spreadsheets to contain macros for security reasons, but we still need to use VBA to perform mass operations on data in the normal workbook. As a result, all of our macros are defined in each employee's PERSONAL.xlsb file and can be called on our normal workbook. Since we run many different macros over this workbook, it is really handy to have shortcuts to call them. The shortcuts are defined in excel as seen here:

[image: Assigning Macro Hotkeys]

The PERSONAL.xlsb file is special because Excel will automatically open this as a hidden background workbook whenever you open any excel file. This is great because it enables you to call user-defined macros in PERSONAL.xlsb on the current workbook, without needing the current workbook to be macro enabled.

The .xlsb is a binary extension and uses some proprietary Microsoft compression algorithm. The issue is that writing macros and VBA code is done through the VBA IDE bundled in Excel. This means that the code that you write isn't stored in plaintext, and excel is acting as a middleman that reads/writes your VBA code to a binary blob in the .xlsb file.

Since we use (and plan on adding) many macros, It would be highly advantageous to code them as plain files in an editor of my choice and use git to keep track of changes. Ideally, I want a development folder with a bunch of different `.vba` files to logically separate each macro. I then want a plain text configuration file that defines optional shortcut keys to each one of the `.vba` code modules.

Then, when I am happy with changes, I want to run a program that uses the [Microsoft Excel Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=vs.140).aspx) to compile this all into a nice PERSONAL.xlsb file that can be easily kept up to date and sent to other employees. I have nearly all of this implemented, but I can't figure out how to assign shortcut keys to a code module.

Here is my example code that compiles VBA files to a `.xlsb` file:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace BinaryCompile
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string path = @"C:\Users\Path\To\Source";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            //Console.WriteLine(path);
            var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add();

            var project = workbook.VBProject;

            include_files(get_vba_files(), ref project);

            excel.MacroOptions();

            workbook.SaveAs(path + "/PERSONAL.xlsb", XlFileFormat.xlExcel12);
            workbook.Close();

            Console.Read();
            excel.Quit();

        }

        static string[] get_vba_files()
        {
            return Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.vba");
        }

        static void include_files(string[] vba_files, ref VBProject project)
        {
            foreach (string source in vba_files)
            {
                var module = project.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
                module.CodeModule.AddFromFile(source);
                module.Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(source);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find any documentation on how to assign shortcut keys to these programatically generated modules.

Answer (score 1):

This is one option, if you're free to modify the vba file. If you create an macro in Excel, assign a shortcut, and then export the module, you will see the file has the following structure:

```vb
Attribute VB_Name = "MyModule"
Sub MyFunction()
Attribute MyFunction.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = "y\n14"
    'Do Your stuff
End Sub

Sub MyFunction2()
Attribute MyFunction2.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = "q\n14"
    'Do more stuff
End Sub
```

The first character in `"y\n14"` and `"q\n14"` will be your shortcut key to be used with `Ctrl` key, in these cases, *Ctrl+y* and *Ctrl+q*.

Side note: I tried your code, and I only could make it work by removing the `excel.MacroOptions();` line.